# Linux Mint partition is visible in Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, hard-drive, windows-8.1, partitioning, linux-mint

I have recently made some changes in my partitions as follows:

Previously, I had 3 drives named: C 150 GiB, D 400 GiB, E: 450 GiB
I installed Windows 8.1 and a partition manager software (EaseUS) on C: and made some changes. I merged 250 GiB of D: into E:, renaming E: to D: and the remaining 150 GiB was named Q:

I installed Linux Mint successfully on Q: (ext3 FS) and now I've got a working dual OS notebook. The problem is that Windows 8.1 still shows drive Q: as an empty NTFS drive. As far as I know, after installing Linux, Windows is not supposed to show its partition anymore. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptom you describe is caused by the Linux partition having an incorrect partition type code. The proper solution is to change that type code. The details of how to do this vary depending on the partitioning software you use. As an example:

1. Boot to Linux.
2. Type `df` to view your mounted filesystems and identify which ones correspond to partitions on `/dev/sda` (assuming that's your disk; if not, adjust here and for the rest of this procedure).
3. Type `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`.
4. If `gdisk` produces output that includes `MBR: MBR only` and a complaint that it's converting MBR data to GPT form, type `q` immediately! You can instead launch `fdisk` on the disk (`sudo fdisk /dev/sda`), and the procedure will be much the same, but with one important difference (noted below).
5. Type `p` to view the partition table and verify that it looks sensible. At least one of your Linux partitions likely has a type code of 0700 (or 07 in `fdisk` on an MBR disk).
6. Type `t` to change a partition's type code. When prompted, enter the number of the partition that has the wrong type code and change it to 8300 (or 83 on an MBR disk when using `fdisk`).
7. If necessary, repeat step #5 for any other misidentified partitions. (It sounds like you've got just one.)
8. Type `p` to view the partition table again. Compare it to what you saw earlier, and ensure it's the same *except* for the partition(s) whose type code(s) you've changed. If you see unexpected changes, type `q` to quit without saving those changes and start over again. (Both `gdisk` and `fdisk` hold their changes in memory until you save them.)
9. Type `w` to save your changes. The program will ask for confirmation. Give it.

After this, Windows should no longer assign the Linux partition(s) drive letters. Unlike the solution offered by Aaron (which basically "plasters over" the problem), this one will continue to work even if you completely delete and re-install Windows, or if you use an emergency disk for maintenance.

This problem could have been caused in any number of ways, including use of very old software to prepare the disk (Linux *used to* "piggyback" on the Windows type code for GPT disks, which was a bad idea), creating the Linux partition with Windows partitioning software, or user error when preparing the partition.

For more on this problem, including the history of the development of the Linux-native GPT type code, see [this page of mine.](http://nessus.rodsbooks.com/linux-fs-code/index.html)

Note that Windows partitioning tools will show all partitions, even those that are not assigned drive letters in Windows. This is normal and desirable -- partitioning tools operate at a lower level than most other tools, so they *must* be able to see and operate on partitions that belong to other OSes.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the Start button and select "Disk Management".  Find your "Q:" partition, right-click on it, and select "Change Driver Letter and Paths...".  From here, you can remove the "Q:" mapping and it will not show up anymore.

It is strange that your Linux drive is showing up as an empty NTFS partition.  I'm wondering if you did something unexpected when setting up your partitions, and it actually *is* an empty NTFS partition, and you still have another Linux partition which is not shown in Windows.  (Maybe the Linux Mint installer shrunk another partition to make room for your 150 GB Linux partition... or something like that.)  You should be able to tell if this is the case by looking at the partitions listed in Disk Management.

Comment: I did what you said. In Disk Management, there's no Q ... I'd installed LM with 5 partitions and DM shows those 5 as basic & primary without any letter. There's no Q. Now this is a freaky confusing behaviour I have never seen before anywhere.